# VennDiagram without group names and with Arial font

Tags: r, fonts, venn-diagram

I have been requested to redo the following Venn diagram in R with Arial font and without the group names... Looking at [VennDiagram manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VennDiagram/VennDiagram.pdf) I do not see how I can do it...

This is my MWE:

```
#install.packages("VennDiagram")
library(VennDiagram)

a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
b <- c(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
c <- c(1,2,10,11,12,5,13,14,15,16)

venn.diagram(list("A" = a, "B" = b, "C" = c),
                 fill = c("red", "blue", "green"), alpha = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5),
                 cat.cex = .75, cex = .75, lty =2, lwd =0.5, fontfamily ="serif",
                 filename = "test.tiff", imagetype = "tiff",
                 height = 3000, width = 3000, resolution = 1500, units = "px",
                 main="TITLE", main.pos=c(0.1,1.05), main.fontfamily="serif", main.cex=.75)
```

[image: test image]

Is it even possible to remove the group names A, B, and C, and change the font family to Arial, or I should think about another approach instead of R?

Besides, could it be possible to add a color legend?

Comment: Seems you have to pass empty strings to `category = rep("", 3)` or you could set the size to zero,,, `cat.cex=0`

Answer (score 5):

To install Arial fonts, use this [manual](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2013/09/09/preparing-figures-for-plos-one-with-r/). 
Then you should be able to change
`fontfamily ="Arial"` and `main.fontfamily="serif"`.

Answer (score 3):

Really rough guess, but do you see:

```
fontfamily ="serif",
```

and:

```
main.fontfamily="serif"
```

Try changing them to Arial and see if it works. I haven't got time to check this out at my computer right now so this is a super fast guess.

To remove the group names, you could probably change them where you assign them in the array:

```
venn.diagram(list("A" = a, "B" = b, "C" = c)
```

Here you can possibly call them what you'd like

Comment: Ops I thought writing Arial didn't work, cause I had written it in "main.fontface", not "main.fontfamiy" hehe. However, I don't seem to be able to remove the A, B, C

Comment: Never used this before so it could be a shot in the dark, can you try shaping the array to look like this:
    venn.diagram(list("" = a, "" = b, "" = c)

Or even better, try not listing them at all, not sure how it'll turn out or effect the rest of your code though

Comment: writing it like list(" " = a, " " = b, " " = c) with spaces is the only way to go it seems

Comment: Odd, as that still gives it a title which is just a blank space, no doubt there is a way to completely remove the title. Can you find where you call and display the Title list? Try removing it or editing it

Comment: That's really odd... I'm clueless right now, I'll have time to check this in about an hour or so if it is not solved by then. The last thing I can think of is just removing the listing all together