# How to Change Venn Diagram Font

Tags: r

I am trying to change the font of my venn diagram to arial.

Based on a prior stackoverflow question here [VennDiagram without group names and with Arial font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072203/venndiagram-without-group-names-and-with-arial-font) I tried adding fontfamily ="arial" to the code, but it did not work.

```
venn.plot <- draw.quad.venn(
area1 = 72,
area2 = 86,
area3 = 50,
area4 = 52,
n12 = 44,
n13 = 27,
n14 = 32,
n23 = 38,
n24 = 32,
n34 = 20,
n123 = 18,
n124 = 17,
n134 = 11,
n234 = 13,
n1234 = 6,
category = c("Workshops", "STEM Tours", "Summer Apprenticeships", 
"Convocation"),
fill = c("antiquewhite4", "cornflowerblue", "gold1", "lightpink2"),
lty = 0, #this gets rid of border
fontfamily ="arial",
cex = 1, 
cat.cex = 2,
cat.col = c("antiquewhite4", "cornflowerblue", "gold1", "lightpink2")
);
```

Comment: Do you have the ``extrafont`` package? Does this work for you? : https://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2013/09/09/preparing-figures-for-plos-one-with-r/

Comment: Yes, I have the extrafont package, but it's not working for this graph.

Answer (score 0):

In my system (Win64), after installing `extrafont` you would need to run `font_import()` (takes a while), and then `loadfonts(device = "win")`. Then you can do something like `wf <- windowsFonts()` and explore `wf`. In my case, I can access Arial with `wf$Arial`, but YMMV. Also, bear in mind that the names of the groups are in the `cat.fontfamily` argument. If you want everyting in Arial,

```
venn.plot <- draw.quad.venn(
    area1 = 72,
    area2 = 86,
    area3 = 50,
    area4 = 52,
    n12 = 44,
    n13 = 27,
    n14 = 32,
    n23 = 38,
    n24 = 32,
    n34 = 20,
    n123 = 18,
    n124 = 17,
    n134 = 11,
    n234 = 13,
    n1234 = 6,
    category = c("Workshops", "STEM Tours", "Summer Apprenticeships", 
                "Convocation"),
    fill = c("antiquewhite4", "cornflowerblue", "gold1", "lightpink2"),
    lty = 0, #this gets rid of border
    fontfamily = wf$Arial,
    cex = 1, 
    cat.cex = 2,
    cat.fontfamily = wf$Arial,
    cat.col = c("antiquewhite4", "cornflowerblue", "gold1", "lightpink2")
);
```